# How to convert the date using R from a MATLAB serial date number?

Tags: r, matlab

I've been given MATLAB data that I'm reading into R and it has a date variable in the MATLAB serial date number format.
I'm trying to convert this into a normal date format in R.

I can select out individual dates and times and convert them using:

```
Matlab2Rdate <- function(val) as.Date(val - 1, origin = "0000-01-01")
Matlab2Rdate(733567.9) = "2008-06-08"
```

OR

```
val <- 733567.9
as.POSIXct((val - 719529)*86400, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC") = "2008-06-08 21:36:00 UTC"
```

But I want to either convert the MATLAB time variable or create a new "date" variable for every observation, not just selected ones.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Where are those observations stored? Your function is already vectorised so this should work `df$date <- Matlab2Rdate(df$col_name)` where `df` is your dataframe and `col_name` is the column name where you have the numbers.

Comment: It's stored in a data.frame (if I'm understanding correctly). The current "date" variable is numerical. I tried your code and got the following error: 
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Time, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1422725

Comment: Can you add first few rows of your dataframe here? Edit your question with output of `dput(head(df, 10))`.

Comment: @RonakShah see edit as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: The purpose of `dput` is that we can copy paste your data as it is and use. You added `dput` as image which we cannot copy and use. Never add data as image. Please add it as plain text which we can copy. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269